# StateFlow collecting multiple emits

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I am emitting multiple values in stateFlow on page load, but all values are not being collected. If I add a delay for the emits all are collected. All emits are of different values. Is there a way to resolve this without adding delay ?

Comment: use `collect` instead of `collectLatest`

Comment: `StateFlow` represents only a single value, not a stream of values, so I imagine it can ignore old values if new one arrives very quickly. Maybe you should use a `SharedFlow`?

Comment: From kotlin doc - *A mutable state flow is created using MutableStateFlow(value) constructor function with the initial value. The value of mutable state flow can be updated by setting its value property. Updates to the value are always conflated. So a slow collector skips fast updates but always collects the most recently emitted value.* link - [StateFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/)